# Im trying to get the average of the numbers and exit the code when user press -1 but it keeps in a infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, average

/*write a program that allows a teacher to enter a percentage mark for each student in a class
the teacher enters a negative mark to indicate that there are no more marks to be entered
once all the marks been entered, the program displays the average percentage mark for the class
author:john 
26/10/2014
*/

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 main()
 {
int i;
int b =-2;
float average;
float marks;
printf("Please enter the students mark and enter -1 when finished\n");


while(i!=-1)
{
    scanf("%f",&marks);
    average=(marks+marks)*i;

}//end loop
printf("print %.2f",i);




 }// end main
```

Comment: `// end loop // end main` are sooo 20th century, let's not use them. Apart from that, if you never change `i`, why/how do you expect it should change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the average you would need to keep track of the running sum and the count of entered marks. Also, be careful about comparing a floating point value for equality, so I would avoid `marks != -1`.

The loop could then be modified as:

```
int i = 0;
float sum = 0;
float average = 0;
float marks = 0;

for (;;)
{
  scanf("%f", &marks);
  if (marks < 0)
  {
    break;
  }
  sum += marks;
  i++;
}
if (i > 0) // avoid division by zero if user enters a negative marks as the first one
{
  average = sum / i;
}
```